# solution for Matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$$
(w*(R_1*P*R_1^{-1})^{-1}+w*(R_2*P*R_2^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}=P_{th}
$$
$R_i$ is a rotation matrix 2*2:
$$
R_i=\left[\begin{matrix}
        cos\theta_i & sin\theta_i \\
        -sin\theta_i & cos\theta_i  \\
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$
$w$ is constant number $${0<w<1}$$and $P_{th}$ is a constant threshold matrix. how can solve this equation for squared matrix $P$ according to matrix mathematics? also it's seem that $P$ have to be a symmetric, positive definite matrix.indeed left term of above equation fuse two ellipse and i want to find those ellipse matrices that their combination satisfy threshold matrix $P_{th}$. I would really appreciate if someone can solve this problem or have useful discussion about it.

Comment: can any one say this matrix function is convex or concave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality can be rewritten $R_1P^{-1}R_1^{-1}+R_2P^{-1}R_2^{-1}=w^{-1}P_{th}^{-1}$. Let $R_1P^{-1}R_1^{-1}=X,R_2R_1^{-1}=R,w^{-1}P_{th}^{-1}=S$. Since $R_1,R_2,w,P_{th}$ are known, it suffices to find $X$ s.t. $X+RXR^{-1}=S$, that is $XR+RX=SR$, where $R$ is a rotation with angle $\theta$. This is a Sylvester equation

cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

The previous equation admits a sole solution in $X$ when $\cos(\theta)\not= 0$.

Comment: may you help me...can you say left side of this function is convex or concave with respect to entry of matrix P?

Comment: @ javad_malekzadeh , if you are interested by my post, then upvote it !

Comment: You proposed an algorithmic solution to solve the equation. I am interested to find a mathematical close solution. I guess that if the left right of equation be convex it can be solved by mathematical convex optimization. I can't prove it yet but it seems to be convex. Can you help me?

Comment: @ javad_malekzadeh , I shew that your problem can be reduced to a linear one (in dimension $2$). In response, you say you prefer to obtain a closed form for the solution and consequently you would to solve a convex optimization problem; I point out that this kind of method does not provide any closed form. Finally, I think that you write about questions that you do not understand.